# Table as input in feature file

Tags: java, cucumber

While I was working on `cucumber` tests with scenario outline and writing feature file, I am currently having 25 arguments in the example table, and I'm presenting them as I saw here:

```
Scenario Outline: Create ABC
Given I open the application
When I enter username as "<username>"
And I enter password as "<password>"
Then I enter title as "<title>"
And press submit
Examples:

| username | password | title |

| Rob      | xyz1      | title1 |

| Bob      | xyz1      | title2 |
```

only I have as I said 25 arguments. Is there is a possibility to transfer the whole example table as `datatable`, and not as 25 arguments in the step file?

Comment: What you want to achieve? To run a scenario with the value pairs of each row in the table (which would work as in your example) or do you want to pass all values of the table to a single step?

Comment: Yes, since I have in one function 25 arguments and it is not very readable, table would have been helpful

Comment: Does it mean you have a table with several rows and 25 columns? Could you please provide a simplified example (could be less columns) of what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

25 arguments does sound like a lot to put in a feature file. Here are possible ways:

1. only put the ID of each row in the example table. So that it will iterate one line per row, and in your scenario, you pull the data from external source with this ID.
2. convert each row into JSON, so that you can have only one column of data in the example table, or just convert some into JSON and leave the basic data as it is in the example table.
3. edit the data in the external tool and import them into your feature file. Some tool like [CukeTest](http://cuketest.com) supports importing data from a CSV file into example, like below:

[image]

Comment: how do I convert a row to json? since I can only read one argument at a time, if I write the example table in the feature file

Comment: the json content should be prepared with some external utility. For example, export the rows to csv file, and write a small script to read the csv and write the json output as a file, then import back.

Answer (score 0):

Having this feature file is good, You need to have the following annotations in your step definitions to transfer all data in example table to the step definition file.

```
@Given("^I open the application$")
@When("^I enter username as \"([^\"]*)\"$")
@When("^I enter password as  \"([^\"]*)\"$")
@Then("^I enter title as \"([^\"]*)\"$")
@Then("^press submit$")
```

**Step Definitions File**

```
package steps;

import cucumber.api.PendingException;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;

public class StepDefs {
    @Given("^I open the application$")
    public void i_open_the_application() throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("=============================================================");
        System.out.println(" Opening the Application ... ");
    }

    @When("^I enter username as \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void i_enter_username_as_username(String username) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println(" Username: " + username);
    }

    @When("^I enter password as  \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void i_enter_password_as_password(String password) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println(" Password: " + password);
    }

    @Then("^I enter title as \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void i_enter_title_as_title(String title) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println(" Title: " + title);
    }

    @Then("^press submit$")
    public void press_submit() throws Throwable {
        System.out.println(" SUBMIT");
        System.out.println("=============================================================");
    }

}
```

I tested it and it's working fine as expected using your data table. 
But what could I recommend is instead of using cucumber data tables, you can insert the test data inside Excel file and read it using the **Apache POI** Library

Comment: It passes everything, but I have 25 arguments in one function, and it is not very readable, so I'm looking for a solution

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by using [qaf-gherkin](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/gherkin_client.html) where you can load examples from external data source like csv/excel/xml/json/database. In that case your feature file will look like:

```
Scenario Outline: Create ABC
Given I open the application
When I enter username as "<username>"
And I enter password as "<password>"
Then I enter title as "<title>"
And press submit
Examples:{'datafile':'resources/testdata.txt'}
```

And your datafile will look like:

```
#col.separator=|
username|password|title
Rob|xyz1|title1
Bob| xyz1|title2
```

Above is example of csv (charter separated values) data provider with | as seperator. You also can use different data providers to provide data from any of excel/xml/json/database.